# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssl, ssh, shared-hosting, openssh

I've wanted to connect my share hosting with ssh. So I generate an ssh key in the ssh action of cpanel and authorized it. Then I've downloaded the private key and drop it in the ./ssh folder of my MacBook.I've used this code to connect my host.

```
ssh -p 2083  username@host IP
```

but I got this error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: There can be many causes.  One possibility is that the VM is shut down, which can easily happen in AWS or Azure if you have auto shutdown enabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I run into a similar case with a small computer I have in my desk. What I did to debug the issue was to run `sshd -t`, which runs the sshd daemon in debug mode. This command reported that the permissions of my keys were invalid. All I had to do then was to go in the folder where the keys are stored and issue `chmod 0600 <your_ssh_keys>`.
Maybe the action you run generated things with the wrong permissions too.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when using docker command with remote host

`docker -H ssh://user@server compose up`

after some digging i found on my remote server in auth logs (/var/log/auth.log) this:

```
Aug  8 14:51:46 user sshd[1341]: error: beginning MaxStartups throttling
Aug  8 14:51:46 user sshd[1341]: drop connection #10 from [some_ip]:32992 on [some_ip]:22 past MaxStartups
```

This lead me to change `MaxStartups` settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. After restarting ssh service everything worked like a charm.

Comment: I am also facing the issue with docker. What value you gave to MaxStartups?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it was happend as I use `ProxyCommand` in ssh config file. In my case the `Host` was not defined correctly which then caused the same error!

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure if the hostname is correct. A typo either in the cmd or configfile gives this error.

then, check the sshd log in the host, to find the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure if my solution is working for yours.
For me, I plan to connect to github via ssh. The same error occurs.
I find the solution in https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/55269
My config file content is as below.

```
#Windows
ProxyCommand "C:\APP\Git\mingw64\bin\connect" -S 127.0.0.1:51837 -a none %h %p

#MacOS
#ProxyCommand nc -v -x 127.0.0.1:51837 %h %p

Host github.com
  User git
  Port 443
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  # change the path here
  IdentityFile "C:\Users\Your_User_Name\.ssh\id_rsa"
  TCPKeepAlive yes

Host ssh.github.com
  User git
  Port 443
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  # change the path here
  IdentityFile "C:\Users\Your_User_Name\.ssh\id_rsa"
  TCPKeepAlive yes
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the host was also the reason - I used gitea as git server and the  .ssh folder and all certs in it required to be not accessible for everyone.

This makes totally sense, but I wished that the error message would give a better hint!