# SSH over CDN HTTP-Proxy

Tags: ssh, cdn

I have a server which i'd like to connect to it using ssh. But the problem is I'm using a cdn http-proxy and have a domain name which connects to port 22 of the server.

when I try connecting i get the error:

`kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

does anyone have an idea what I could do?

Comment: maybe try this out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73292521/13861840 Hope it helps
Kr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH traffic is not supported by Cloudflare's proxy service, as it is not HTTP/HTTPS traffic. Therefore, you cannot directly use Cloudflare's HTTP proxy to connect to your SSH server. However, you can use Cloudflare Argo Tunnel or a VPN solution to access your SSH server over the internet while keeping your traffic secure.

Comment: That's true. back then I wasn't thinking clearly.